# npm package babel error in my own package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jsx, babeljs

I have created my own npm package but while using in a test application am getting the following error: Add @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.

> Note: I've written my component in JSX

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "my-test-package",
      "version": "1.4.3",
      "description": "Rich form fieds with simple and complex validation",
      "main": "index.js",
      "homepage": "https://github.com",
      "url": "https://github.com/",
      "license": "MIT",
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --env  --open --hot --port",
        "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production"
      },
      "author": "Harish",
      "contributors": [
        "Harish"
      ],
      "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^16.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.5.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "webpack": "^4.41.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
      }
}
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that to your `.babelrc` file, not `package.json`

Comment: added my bable rc file

Comment: Add @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx to the plugins section

Comment: still gettting the error as follows

    + 33 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/intelli-fields/index.js 65:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (65:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     render() {
|         return (
>             <div className="intelli-field">
|                 {this.props.type == 'hidden'?(
|                    ""
 @ ./src/components/App.js 24:0-43 40:98-111
 @ ./src/index.js

Comment: this is my GitHub URL: https://github.com/Hahkarthick/intelli-fields